# What does "constipado" mean?

Tags: definiciones, false-friend

I am studying Spanish in college and I am stumped on a problem. The question is

> "en español estar constipado/a es lo mismo que ___________"

Which translates to:

> "In Spanish being 'constipated' is the same as..."

right? The answer choices are:

1. estar resfriado
2. el baile
3. Caracas
4. muy bueno

I have no idea what the answer would be, any help? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking up *constipado* in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes it translates to constipation

Comment: @Nate No, it does not.

Answer (score 4):

### False Friends

Though English *constipated* and Spanish *constipado* are cognate (coming from the same root word in Latin meaning 'compacted'), they are false friends, having taken on different meanings in the modern languages: *constipado* means congested nasally, as in suffering from a cold.

The general Spanish word for constipation is *estreñimiento*.

### English influence

However, in some American dialects of Spanish *constipado* does have the same meaning as *constipated/constipation*, due to influence from the English word:

> [**constipado.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=constipado)
>   **I.   1.**    m. *Py, Ar:NO.* Indigestión. pop.
>    **2.** *Py, Ar:NO.* Estreñimiento. pop.
>
> **constipado, -a.** <sub>(Del ingl. *constipated*, estreñido).</sub>
>   **I.    1.**    adj. *EU, Py; Ar:NO.* pop. *Referido a persona*, que padece un trastorno producido por falta de digestión.
>    **2.** *Py, Ar:E,N, Ur.* *Referido a persona*, que padece estreñimiento. pop.